# Nature of IP addresses as it pertains to online voting

Tags: ip

I have an online contest where people vote for a sports team by filling out an html form.

When looking at the data on any given day, we notice that we often get hundreds of votes per hour coming from the same IP address.  Yesterday we got hundreds of per hour from 111.111.111.111 and 222.222.222.222.  Then today, we get hundreds of votes per hour from 333.333.333.333 and 444.444.444.444 and 555.555.555.555.  I automatically suspect foul play such as a bot, or perhaps a team of employees from the same building voting on behalf of other users.

However, when i ran an sql query to show votes per hour, I noticed that the votes from these IP addresses spiked around noon and late nights between 9pm and midnight.   I'd imagine this is consistent with real user voting behaviour, because people want to vote during their non-work hours.

I'm confused, the IP addresses seem to imply foul play, but the votes per hour seem to imply legitimate votes.

So my question is:
**Is it possible for entire cities and towns to use the same IP address?**  I'd like an explanation on how IP addresses work so that I can determine if it is an effective way to detect foul votes.

Comment: Are you really registering 555.555.555.555 as an IP address? That's not even close to being a valid IPv4 address (the numbers are between 0 and 255 max).

Comment: @mat thanks mat, the 555.555.555.555 speaks to my ignorance of IP addresses.  I used a number like that cause easy to type into stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPs are not shared as much today as they were 20 years ago. Fact is, so many different IPs are issued that the IPv4 pool is being drained out and we are close to having to resort exclusively to IPv6 to expand the IP pool.

Anyway, this is definitely fool play. Input a limit on each IP and a ban after too many attemps to vote from the same place and you should be fine. Depending on your system/implementation, you could use cookies, look client details (navigator used, etc...),... to separate multiple users with the same IP.

Comment: Good luck if you have any users in, say, Qatar.

Comment: @Wooble Or China =) Or if everyone is voting from Red Hat HQ... Okay, I didn't think this one through but I try, I try =)

Answer (score 0):

I'd think it was fraud. You should probably implement vote throttling from a specific IP address.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses can be easily flubbed.

Try identifying your users by something different (like a username)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have scores of people coming from the same address - the stories are legion about people being banned from certain sites because their internet provider proxies all webtraffic through one address.